# How do I compute differences between numbers in a list?

Tags: r, loops, vector

I have a list of numbers:

```
head(x[[1]])
[1] 10990.16 10959.95 10942.02 10935.00 10867.84 10863.00
```

and I would like to compute the difference between all adjacent numbers (n - (n-1)). In the case above, the output would be 30.21, 17.93, 7.02,...

Does anyone have any suggestions for computing all these values at once?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
x <- c(10990.16, 10959.95, 10942.02, 10935.00, 10867.84, 10863)
abs(diff(x))
#[1] 30.21 17.93  7.02 67.16  4.84
```

or

```
abs(x[-1]-x[-length(x)])
#[1] 30.21 17.93  7.02 67.16  4.84
```

or

```
 head(x,-1)- tail(x,-1)
```

Comment: Simple as that. Thanks.

Comment: @user1038055 yes, it is.

Comment: @David Arenburg  Looks like it is, (I could be wrong) :-)